# How to find NOT open files with lsof

Tags: bash, ubuntu, lsof

Say, I got a specific task to find files that are **not open**. I understand how to get a list of open files with lsof (`lsof +D`). Furthermore I need to find them only in so called 1st level subdirectories. To do this i use `find` command with `maxdepth 1` operand.

smth like this: `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -ls >dirlist`

Then, in a while loop i am trying to use **lsof** to check the list of directories (parental and 1 level sub) for **NOT open** files but i am completely green to bash. Say i might be able to get a list of OPEN files, but it's not what i need. Any ideas are welcomed.

Thanks for any help-

cheers

Update: `awk` might be helpful, as far as I understand. Also `case` and `shift` maybe?

**Update 1:** I figured out just now that I am supposed to call (use, invoke, not sure which word is correct) for `lsof` once only, that's why my `while` loop isn't a suitable solution. Moreover, I need to stdout a list of directories that have **no open files**, each in a separate line. It's not that hard, i kinda got it working, just trying to clarify what the tsak is. The problem is that i don't know how to redirect a list of directories to `lsof` without a `while` loop. 
smth like this doesn't work the way i want it to:
`file="path"; name=$(cat "$file")`

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of files returned by `lsof`, you want to remove those from `dirlist` and print the rest.

```
lsof +D . | grep -vFxf - dirlist
```

If `lsof` descends the directory to a deeper level and finds files which are not in `dirlist`, the only effect will be that `grep` cannot find and remove those, so apart from a minor inefficiency, that should be harmless.

`grep -F` says the search expressions are exact strings, not regular expressions; `-x` says the match needs to be an entire line; `-v` says to remove matches; and `-f -` says to read the search patterns from standard input.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like an idea to give it a try. If it doesn't work out, i'll let you know ))

Answer (score 1):

Use **find** command

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read myfile ; do fuser -s $myfile || echo $myfile ; done
```

**"find -maxdepth 1 -type f"** - find all files in **-maxdepth 1** directory
**"while read myfile ; do fuser -s $myfile || echo $myfile ; done"** - check if file does not have its process(it means file is not used) then print this filename

Comment: Too bad I am to use `lsof`. Found this solution a couple hours ago. Thank you for your help though

Comment: Be aware of the race conditions this command introduces. You can't trust this output